# How can I style Material UI table header?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-table

How can I style Materials' UI table header?

Maybe something like add classes with useStyle.

```js
<TableHead >
            <TableRow >
                <TableCell hover>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
</TableHead>
```

I want to add style to the table header

Answer (score 13):

I personally used "makeStyles" for styling but you can use "withStyles" as well.

Here is the ***table***:

```
<TableHead >
    <TableRow className={classes.root}>
        <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
        <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
</TableHead>
```

Here is the ***styles***:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({

    root: {
        "& .MuiTableCell-head": {
            color: "white",
            backgroundColor: "blue"
        },
    }
});
```

Here is the ***output***:

[image: Material UI table header color change]

Answer (score 9):

you can use `withStyles` and create an custom element with your own style like this. you can check the working scenario

[image: Edit strange-cherry-832ug]

```js
const TableHead = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'orange'
  }
}))(MuiTableHead);

const TableHeaderCell = withStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    color: 'white'
  }
}))(TableCell);
```

```html
<TableHead>
  <TableRow>
    <TableHeaderCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableHeaderCell>
    <TableHeaderCell align="right">Calories</TableHeaderCell>
    <TableHeaderCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableHeaderCell>
    <TableHeaderCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableHeaderCell>
    <TableHeaderCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableHeaderCell>
  </TableRow>
</TableHead>
```

[image: CustomHeaderStyle]

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `sx` props in the `<TableRow>` to style your table header and change the color to yours.

```
 sx={{
      "& th": {
        color: "rgba(96, 96, 96)",
        backgroundColor: "pink"
      }
    }}
```

Here's my CodeSandbox sample: https://codesandbox.io/embed/customizedtableheader-nl4bio?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Check more information about `sx` in [here](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to style all of your TableHeaders globally by adjusting your theme:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTableCell: {
      head: {
        color: "grey",
      }
    }
  },
  palette: {
    primary: {
      ... 
    },
    secondary: {
     ...
    }
  },
});
```

Note: this is in the MUI v4 format, the v5 format is slightly different. Check the [MUI v4 -> v5 migration](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#theme-structure) guide for details.

Answer (score 0):

Add style inside `<TableHead>` like below:

**NOTE:**

- `backgroundColor`: this is the color of header background
- `color`: this is the color of the font inside the header

```
<TableHead style={{backgroundColor:'red', color: 'white',}}>
```

After adding it to your code, it would look like this:

```
<TableHead style={{backgroundColor:'red', color: 'white',}}>
            <TableRow className={classes.root}>
                <TableCell>Dessert (100g serving)</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Calories</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Fat&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Carbs&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="right">Protein&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
```